# parse json data array inside array

Tags: android, json, web-services, parsing

```
   {
   "TABLE":[
      {
         "ROW":[
            {
               "COL":[
                  {
                     "DATA":"< OutBoundSMS PhoneId='3' PhoneNo='1111111111' MessageText='OutBound SMS Application Test' />"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

How to parse json array like this format?
I am getting this error while parsing: "cannot be converted to json object".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parse Current Json String as:

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject("Your Json String");
JSONArray jsonarray = json.getJSONArray("TABLE");

for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++){

  JSONObject jsonnew=jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
  JSONArray jsonarrayROW = jsonnew.getJSONArray("ROW");

   for(int j=0;j<jsonarrayROW.length();j++){
     JSONObject jsonnewtwo=jsonarrayROW.getJSONObject(j);
     JSONArray jsonarrayCOL = jsonnewtwo.getJSONArray("COL");

      for(int k=0;k<jsonarrayCOL.length();k++){

        JSONObject jsonnewthree=jsonarrayCOL.getJSONObject(k);

        //get DATA here

           String str_data=jsonnewthree.getString("DATA");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: its work but again i wont able to get  the data in hashmap from OutBoundSMS tag so plz suggest

Comment: @NitinGupta : string you are getting in DATA is not a xml or not an other json string. so you will need to split it on the base of `' ` and use replace for removing unwanted characters

Answer (score 0):

see here

```
String jsonStr = '{"menu": {' + 
        '"id": "file",' + 
        '"value": "File",' + 
        '"popup": {' + 
          '"menuitem": [' + 
            '{"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},' + 
            '{"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},' + 
            '{"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}' + 
          ']' + 
        '}' + 
      '}}';
```

here see good example [JSON PARSING](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_JSON_Parser_Example)

Comment: but its array of array could u suugest again NagarjunaReddy.P

Answer (score 0):

**Its Working parse json data array inside array**

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=28.4759618,77.3140897&destination=28.3936072,77.3172154&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true

    {
       "geocoded_waypoints" : [
          {
             "geocoder_status" : "OK",
             "place_id" : "ChIJzfXobhTnDDkRJQ2M4AEkun8",
             "types" : [ "street_address" ]
          },
          {
             "geocoder_status" : "OK",
             "place_id" : "ChIJrz2dDk_cDDkRmnC23K0BpD4",
             "types" : [ "street_address" ]
          }
       ],
       "routes" : [
          {
             "bounds" : {
                "northeast" : {
                   "lat" : 28.4808871,
                   "lng" : 77.3195229
                },
                "southwest" : {
                   "lat" : 28.3932808,
                   "lng" : 77.30536649999999
                }
             },
             "copyrights" : "Map data ©2017 Google",
             "legs" : [
                {
                   "distance" : {
                      "text" : "11.9 km",
                      "value" : 11902
                   },
                   "duration" : {
                      "text" : "22 mins",
                      "value" : 1313
                   },
                   "end_address" : "384, Sector-16, Sector 15A, Faridabad, Haryana 121007, India",
                   "end_location" : {
                      "lat" : 28.3936165,
                      "lng" : 77.31753990000001
                   },
                   "start_address" : "A-105, Ashoka Enclave Part II, Sector 37, Faridabad, Haryana 121003, India",
                   "start_location" : {
                      "lat" : 28.4759614,
                      "lng" : 77.3139839
                   },
                   "steps" : [
                      {
                         "distance" : {
                            "text" : "14 m",
                            "value" : 14
                         },
                         "duration" : {
                            "text" : "1 min",
                            "value" : 3
                         },
                         "end_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.4760899,
                            "lng" : 77.31398329999999
                         },
                         "html_instructions" : "Head \u003cb\u003enorth\u003c/b\u003e",
                         "polyline" : {
                            "points" : "wuxlDkk{vMY?"
                         },
                         "start_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.4759614,
                            "lng" : 77.3139839
                         },
                         "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                      },
                      {
                         "distance" : {
                            "text" : "0.4 km",
                            "value" : 440
                         },
                         "duration" : {
                            "text" : "2 mins",
                            "value" : 116
                         },
                         "end_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.4766301,
                            "lng" : 77.3097228
                         },
                         "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eOld Sher Shah Suri Road\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eSarai Khawaja Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
                         "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                         "polyline" : {
                            "points" : "qvxlDkk{vMApB?Z?jB?bACvDAx@?T@v@?@Dx@?H?FADABCBw@bAQRY`@"
                         },
                         "start_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.4760899,
                            "lng" : 77.31398329999999
                         },
                         "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                      },
                      {
                         "distance" : {
                            "text" : "0.5 km",
                            "value" : 503
                         },
                         "duration" : {
                            "text" : "1 min",
                            "value" : 81
                         },
                         "end_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.4808871,
                            "lng" : 77.30797579999999
                         },
                         "html_instructions" : "Slight \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eOld Sher Shah Suri Road\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eSarai Khawaja Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
                         "maneuver" : "turn-slight-right",
                         "polyline" : {
                            "points" : "}yxlDwpzvMIDiF|AcBh@{Bp@eGhByBp@"
                         },
                         "start_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.4766301,
                            "lng" : 77.3097228
                         },
                         "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                      },
                      {
                         "distance" : {
                            "text" : "0.3 km",
                            "value" : 255
                         },
                         "duration" : {
                            "text" : "1 min",
                            "value" : 50
                         },
                         "end_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.4808239,
                            "lng" : 77.30536649999999
                         },
                         "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eMain Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
                         "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                         "polyline" : {
                            "points" : "qtylD{ezvMHnEBxH"
                         },
                         "start_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.4808871,
                            "lng" : 77.30797579999999
                         },
                         "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                      },
                      {
                         "distance" : {
                            "text" : "1.0 km",
                            "value" : 1013
                         },
                         "duration" : {
                            "text" : "2 mins",
                            "value" : 125
                         },
                         "end_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.4717998,
                            "lng" : 77.30594619999999
                         },
                         "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eNH19\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eNH44\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by Hotel Saffron Kiran (on the left in 1.0&nbsp;km)\u003c/div\u003e",
                         "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                         "polyline" : {
                            "points" : "ctylDquyvMhA?^An@?lAEfAGrEQzBMH?DALEJGzCw@TC`@C^AV?P?T@rALL?v@B\\?VAz@CjB@h@?X?fBG~@B^NrCKTA"
                         },
                         "start_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.4808239,
                            "lng" : 77.30536649999999
                         },
                         "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                      },
                      {
                         "distance" : {
                            "text" : "7.5 km",
                            "value" : 7549
                         },
                         "duration" : {
                            "text" : "10 mins",
                            "value" : 624
                         },
                         "end_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.4041209,
                            "lng" : 77.3116127
                         },
                         "html_instructions" : "Keep \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e to stay on \u003cb\u003eNH19\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eNH44\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by Bank Of India (on the left in 2.4&nbsp;km)\u003c/div\u003e",
                         "maneuver" : "keep-right",
                         "polyline" : {
                            "points" : "w{wlDeyyvM|HU`DMrAEnQu@jASVCXEpGUfDM`BGl@ED?z@CrAGpAEdBI^AfF[~DSvLa@xJ_@lFSvEQlHQlIa@zHUnIa@~FWbBItBGfDIbDMrAP|DMnCMxBEl@?`BGtBMhAG`H[d@AnEQZAxBGbBGfFSxBIpBI`GSfEOlCIVATAh@Ch@AzFWtQu@rHWd@C~J_@`FQl@A`@Ct@AnAE`@Cr@EhCI^A\\Al@El@Ch@ApCOxBI\\AnDOvBG|BIdESzGU|DMvAG`@CdDOnAE~CIf@ElAClDM"
                         },
                         "start_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.4717998,
                            "lng" : 77.30594619999999
                         },
                         "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                      },
                      {
                         "distance" : {
                            "text" : "11 m",
                            "value" : 11
                         },
                         "duration" : {
                            "text" : "1 min",
                            "value" : 4
                         },
                         "end_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.404129,
                            "lng" : 77.3117281
                         },
                         "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eGovernment College Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
                         "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                         "polyline" : {
                            "points" : "wtjlDq|zvMAW"
                         },
                         "start_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.4041209,
                            "lng" : 77.3116127
                         },
                         "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                      },
                      {
                         "distance" : {
                            "text" : "0.3 km",
                            "value" : 274
                         },
                         "duration" : {
                            "text" : "1 min",
                            "value" : 31
                         },
                         "end_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.4016677,
                            "lng" : 77.31193089999999
                         },
                         "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eLal Bahadur Shastri Marg\u003c/b\u003e",
                         "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                         "polyline" : {
                            "points" : "ytjlDi}zvMz@CzBMz@Ah@ClEO"
                         },
                         "start_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.404129,
                            "lng" : 77.3117281
                         },
                         "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                      },
                      {
                         "distance" : {
                            "text" : "0.7 km",
                            "value" : 677
                         },
                         "duration" : {
                            "text" : "2 mins",
                            "value" : 100
                         },
                         "end_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.4018048,
                            "lng" : 77.318851
                         },
                         "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eLal Bahadur Shastri Marg\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by Sun Flag Hospital &amp; Research Centre (on the left in 650&nbsp;m)\u003c/div\u003e",
                         "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                         "polyline" : {
                            "points" : "mejlDq~zvMA]?_A?sD?gD?yC?_F?q@EiDIwCCcBC{A"
                         },
                         "start_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.4016677,
                            "lng" : 77.31193089999999
                         },
                         "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                      },
                      {
                         "distance" : {
                            "text" : "0.9 km",
                            "value" : 936
                         },
                         "duration" : {
                            "text" : "2 mins",
                            "value" : 126
                         },
                         "end_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.3934097,
                            "lng" : 77.3195229
                         },
                         "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e at \u003cb\u003eSector 16 Rd\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by Gymkhana Club - I (on the right)\u003c/div\u003e",
                         "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                         "polyline" : {
                            "points" : "gfjlDyi|vMnAGrNg@nBGtBInIUlDKdJa@"
                         },
                         "start_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.4018048,
                            "lng" : 77.318851
                         },
                         "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                      },
                      {
                         "distance" : {
                            "text" : "0.2 km",
                            "value" : 193
                         },
                         "duration" : {
                            "text" : "1 min",
                            "value" : 41
                         },
                         "end_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.3932808,
                            "lng" : 77.3175523
                         },
                         "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e",
                         "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                         "polyline" : {
                            "points" : "yqhlD_n|vMPrE@nADdB"
                         },
                         "start_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.3934097,
                            "lng" : 77.3195229
                         },
                         "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                      },
                      {
                         "distance" : {
                            "text" : "37 m",
                            "value" : 37
                         },
                         "duration" : {
                            "text" : "1 min",
                            "value" : 12
                         },
                         "end_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.3936165,
                            "lng" : 77.31753990000001
                         },
                         "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eDestination will be on the left\u003c/div\u003e",
                         "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                         "polyline" : {
                            "points" : "_qhlDua|vMcA@"
                         },
                         "start_location" : {
                            "lat" : 28.3932808,
                            "lng" : 77.3175523
                         },
                         "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                      }
                   ],
                   "traffic_speed_entry" : [],
                   "via_waypoint" : []
                }
             ],
             "overview_polyline" : {
                "points" : "wuxlDkk{vMY?ApB?fCEjIF|BGTiAvAY`@IDmIfCaKzCyBp@HnEBxHhA?nAAtCM~Ia@XMpD{@`AEh@?hBNdAB|ECbA?fBG~@B^NrCKrIWtFSnQu@jASp@IxLc@pEQjHYfLo@pXaAdMe@lHQlIa@zHUnIa@bJa@|GQbDMrAPlI[fDEvEUjJc@jK]fd@_BdJ_@h[mAdLc@fJYnHYlNk@jRu@rQo@tFUfEOzFQAWz@CvDOvFSAyL?yJE{EM{FC{AnAGbRo@dM_@lDKdJa@RbHDdBcA@"
             },
             "summary" : "NH19/NH44",
             "warnings" : [],
             "waypoint_order" : []
          }
       ],
       "status" : "OK"
    }
```

**Handle**

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Dialog mDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        callApiArrayInsideArray();
    }


    private void callApiArrayInsideArray() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        // TODO Send parameter using this in volley apis
        /*try {
            jsonObject.put("UserId", "abc");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
//        String url = Constants.GetData;
        String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=28.4759618,77.3140897&destination=28.3936072,77.3172154&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true";

        mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Please wait", true);
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);


        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.i("tag", "Volley response: " + response.toString());
                if (mDialog != null) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                }
                // TODO when Success Response  then set parse data in list view
                parseResponse(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (mDialog != null) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                }
                Log.i("tag", "Volley error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    private void parseResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("routes");

            Log.e("MainActivity", "jsonArray --> " + jsonArray.toString(2));
            if (jsonArray != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonnew = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray jsonarrayROW = jsonnew.getJSONArray("legs");

                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonarrayROW.length(); j++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonnewtwo = jsonarrayROW.getJSONObject(j);
                        JSONArray jsonarrayCOL = jsonnewtwo.getJSONArray("steps");

                        for (int k = 0; k < jsonarrayCOL.length(); k++)
                        {
                            JSONObject jsonnewthree = jsonarrayCOL.getJSONObject(k);
                            String str_data = jsonnewthree.getString("html_instructions");
                            Log.e("Keshav", "html_instructions -> " + str_data);
                        }
                    }
                    Log.e("Keshav", "GeoEvent List->");
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add Dependency in build.gradle file

Comment: compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'